# why is return SFINAE conversion operator not working?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++17

```
struct A
{
  template <typename T>
  constexpr explicit operator
  std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, int>{},
    int
  >() const noexcept
  {
    return -1;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a;

  std::cout << int(a) << std::endl;
}
```

The error is `clang-7.0.1`:

```
<source>:21:16: error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'A' to 'int'
  std::cout << int(a) << std::endl;
               ^~~~~
<source>:7:22: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
  constexpr explicit operator
                     ^
```

Comment: Note that in your (simplified) case, you might simply have conversion `operator int() const noexcept`.

Comment: its a minimum example of what was bothering me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That pattern just doesn't work for conversion functions. The problem is, in order to determine if `a` is convertible to `int`, we look for an `operator int()` - but what we get is:

```
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, int>{}, int>
```

That's a non-deduced context - so we don't find `int`.

You have to move the condition into a defaulted parameter:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>, int> = 0>
constexpr explicit operator T() const noexcept { return -1; }
```

This way, we can deduce `T` and then let SFINAE do its magic. Note that you don't need `decay` since we don't have any kind of reference.

Comment: Would you mind expanding your workaround to the case of 2 template conversion operators? (there will be a declaration clash with your SFINAE approach). Default parameter within the ()?

Comment: @user1095108 If that means what I'm guessing it means, there's no clash. You can't stick a parameter in the `()`s

Comment: Might be less confusing if it ended `, bool> =true>` instead of `,int> =0>`.  Still equally magical, but avoids reusing `int` type in unrelated context that can confuse here.